# msdeploy mvc to Windows7 getting ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE and 404

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-7-x64, msdeploy

I'm trying to do `msdeploy` of a MVC app to a windows7 box, running on command-line. And kept getting this error:

> Error Code: ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE
>   More Information: Could not connect to the destination computer ("192.168.xxx.xxx"
>   ). On the destination computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that
>   the required process ("The Web Management Service") is started.
>   Error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
>   Error count: 1.

I've verified both Wmsvc (seems this is being used) and MsDepSvc are running. And firewall are disabled. In the browser when I visit https://192.168.xxx.xxx:8172/msdeploy.axd, I got a Server Error 404, seems a bit further than where the command-line stopped.

Most of instructions on setting up IIS7 and Web deployment I could find online is for MS Servers. Both my local machine and the Windows7 machine has the same version of Msdeploy installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For non-server operating systems (i.e. Windows 7) the Web Deploy publish via Web Management Service is not supported. Instead you will have to use the Remote Agent Service, this is an admin only publishing service. You can find more info at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569059(v=WS.10).aspx.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Sayed! It's probably less than a smart thing to try anyways..

Answer (score 9):

I had exactly the same issue with a VM on Azure, and the solution was to **enable first the IIS Management Service and then install Web Deploy** (I used Web Platform Installer). Seems that the installation order matters. You can find a blog entry I wrote about this here http://davidjrh.intelequia.com/2012/10/configurando-web-platform-installer-y.html

Comment: Thanks, fixed my issue. Finally able to deploy now, again.

Comment: When you install, make sure to select Custom in the wizard and install all components of Web Deploy https://port135.com/2019/07/29/could-not-reach-the-web-deploy-endpoint-specified-virtual-machine/

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue using MSDeploy to deploy my web application to remote IIS 7.5 web server running windows 7. I have just figured out how to fix the problem today after reading Sayed's post, so I wanna post my solution here for anyone who would run into this problem like me. Try this:

- Enable IIS Management Service (in control panel >> add or remove features >> add or remove windows features)
- Install Web Deploy (http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy)
- Open cmd with Administrative privilege, type “net start msdepsvc” to start the “Web Deploy Agent Service”.
- Check this link in your browser: **`http://serveraddress/MsDeployAgentService/`**, if it prompts for username and password, MsDeployAgentService is running on server, go to the next step.
- In VS, **type in `http://serveraddress/MsDeployAgentService/` in Service URL while creating publish, instead of `https://serveraddress:8172/MsDeploy.axd`**, and click test connection. It should be ok now.

Comment: Thank you Worked like charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

After checking the Management Service and Web Deploy 3.0 were correctly installed, I found that (from VS2012 at least) the Service URL seems to matter here too, attempting to publish to any of the following did not work for me:

- FQDN (localmachine.domain.local)
- Domain IP Address (172.22.xxx.xxx)
- Loop-back IP (127.0.0.1)

Whereas the following DID work:

- localhost
- NetBIOS name (localmachine)

Comment: Had you adjusted the SSL certificate that the Management Service uses?